# RDP and pinging works fine, but other applications cannot connect

Tags: windows, networking

I have just installed Windows Server 2016 Std on a dedicated server. Network settings all appear to be fine including DNS servers (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4). This is a very routine setup for me.

I am able to:

- RDP into the server
- Ping and tracert any IP or web address from the server (e.g. 8.8.8.8, google.com,
  bbc.co.uk)

Not able to:

- Browse with Internet Explorer (not even to IP addresses)
- Install Google Chrome (Says no internet connection)
- Pretty much anything else that requires an internet connection.

I have doubled checked the network settings. IP address, netmask, gateway and DNS servers are all correct, the fact I can RDP and ping suggests they are all okay.

Windows firewall is disabled and hardware firewall is allowing all connections.

Comment: just to confirm the gateway and routing is fine - use tracert to somewhere

Comment: Results of a tracert: http://i.imgur.com/on8H6CH.png

Comment: next thing - firewall - any deny output rules? Also - do you have a firewall at your location, which permis 80/443 outbound traffic only from certain address (like from a proxy server)?

Comment: Windows firewall is off and hardware firewall is set to allow all. No proxy server.

Comment: Ok so we know that outbound ICMP and DNS is allowed, can you check the firewall logs to double check that your port 80/443 traffic is actually leaving the premises?